# $L= \left( \frac{1}{r\sin\theta} \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi} \hat{\phi} - \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial }{\partial \theta} \hat{\theta} \right) $

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, vector-analysis

Surely I'm making a trivial calculation error but I can not find it.

Let:
$$L(r,\theta,\phi)= \frac{\hbar}{i} r \left( \frac{1}{r\sin\theta} \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi} \hat{\phi} - \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial }{\partial \theta} \hat{\theta} \right)$$
$$L^2=L\cdot L= -\hbar^2 r^2 \left( \frac{1}{r\sin\theta} \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi} \hat{\phi} - \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial }{\partial \theta} \hat{\theta} \right)^2=$$
$$= -\hbar^2 r^2 \left( \frac{1}{r\sin\theta} \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi} \hat{\phi} - \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial }{\partial \theta} \hat{\theta} \right) \cdot \left( \frac{1}{r\sin\theta} \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi} \hat{\phi} - \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial }{\partial \theta} \hat{\theta} \right)=$$
$$-\hbar^2 \left( \frac{1}{\sin^2(\theta)} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial \phi^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial \theta^2} \right)$$

But I know that the correct result is: 
$$L^2=-\hbar^2 \left( \frac{1}{\sin^2(\theta)} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial \phi^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial \theta^2} + \cot\theta \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \right)$$

Comment: The vectors $\hat{\phi}$ and $\hat{\theta}$ are also coordinate dependent.

Comment: Also, you would be better off writing the diff'l operators 'last', e.g, $$  L= \left( \hat{\phi}\frac{1}{r\sin\theta} \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}  - \hat{\theta}\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial }{\partial \theta}  \right).$$
The way it was written originally, formally it looks like the operators are applied to the vectors. Reordering will make clearer that the product rule comes into play in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that if you change $\theta$, the direction of $\hat\phi$ changes. You should be able to prove that $$\frac{\partial \hat\theta}{\partial \phi}=\hat\phi\cos\theta$$
If you plug this into your equation, you will get the missing term.

Comment: Much easier to calculate $L_x$, $L_y$, and $L_z$ in terms of spherical coordinates

Comment: And also the coefficient of $\hat \phi$ depends on $\theta$. The partial wrt $\theta$ will act on that too (i.e., I mean it cannot be treated as a constant wrt $\theta$).

Comment: Correct, but then you are left with $\hat\theta\cdot\hat\phi=0$ for that term

Comment: Yes - but the OP should notice that!